# Hidden YouTube player shows in buttons

Tags: youtube, embed, hidden

This problem only occurs on Chrome.

I have a embed youtube player on my website which is hidden and located behind my main design. Once I show

```
$("#trailer").show();
$("#flyer").hide();
```

then hide the player again :

```
$("#trailer").hide();
$("#flyer").show();
```

my main design acts weird : whenever I move my mouse over a link/button/anything actionable it displays a portion of the hidden player.

Here is a not-working example : http://movies.expaflyr.com/68721
(Click on the poster then on "Watch Trailer", close it and mouse-overs will cause bugs)

I don't know how to fix this. Does anyone understand what's was going on?